# Enable media playback without user action for Android

Tags: android, cordova

When I looked for a preference to enable media player to start playing a video automatically [on the official document](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html),
I found the exact option for ios (`MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction`).

However, there isn't any android-equivalent option for this.
Is it not possible to autoplay media on android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to use Android's `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true/false)` method to control the media playback behavior.
The place to do this is in `onCreate()` in `MainActivity.java` file.
(Thank you Amit K. Saha!)

It's under `platforms/android/app/src/main/java/whatever/your/namespace/MainActivity.java`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.webkit.WebSettings; // ----- ADDED
import android.webkit.WebView; // ----- ADDED

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        // ----- ADDED
        WebView wv = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in android cordova. There is an alternative.

```
public class YourActivity extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
           moveTaskToBack(true);
        }


        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        WebSettings ws = super.appView.getSettings();
        ws.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); // its true by default
    }
}
```

Android Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)

**Update:**

it seems `getSettings()` isn't there anymore from `appView`, in that case following should work

```
WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was almost there with your code, but I had to fix it a little. (I also posted it)

Comment: @sora Ideally if it solved , you could have accepted the solution :) Thanks again!!

Comment: I am getting error : Error: cannot find symbol
        WebSettings ws = super.appView.getSettings();

Comment: I get the error"cannot find symbol" as well. Is there a solution?

Comment: it seems getSettings() isn't there any more, in that case following should work

WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();

Comment: Unfortunately same issue: cannot find symbol

Comment: while line? maybe you can ask a new question & share your code block?